# CUDA kernel only launches and runs at some grid sizes

Tags: cuda

I'm actually working with CUDA and i'm trying to optimize a program using this technology. So i've got a big kernel that I must launch between 100k+ time and 100M+ time maybe billions ?

So I read using a dim3 variable allow to launch that amount of threads(cf : https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/621867/size-limitation-for-1d-arrays-in-cuda-/?offset=7)

I got a sample code that (on my gtx970) run sometime and sometime doesn't.

```
#ifndef PROPAGATORSAT_CUH_
# define PROPAGATORSAT_CUH
# define M_PI (3.14159265358979323846)
# define TWO_PI (2 * M_PI)
# define TOTAL_TIME (615359.772)
# define STEP (0.771)
# define NB_IT (TOTAL_TIME / (double)STEP)
# define NB_THREADS (1024)
# define NB_BLOCKS (int)((NB_IT + NB_THREADS - 1) / NB_THREADS)

# include <cmath>
# include <cfloat>
# include <stdio.h>
# include "../common/book.h"
# include "cuda_runtime.h"
# include "device_launch_parameters.h"
# define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

class                           Global
{
public:
    const double                _ITURadEarth = 6378145.0;
    const double                _ITUGravCst = 3.986012E5;
    const double                _ITUJ2 = 0.001082636;
    const double                _J2000AngleDeg = 0;//-79.8058;
    const double                _J2000AngleRad = 0;//TO_RAD(_J2000AngleDeg);
    const double                _ITUAngleRateEarthRot = 4.1780745823E-3;
    const double                _ITUAngleRateEarthRotRad = degToRad(_ITUAngleRateEarthRot);

public:
             __device__ double  myAsin(double angle);
    __host__ __device__ double  myAcos(double angle);
    __host__ __device__ double  negPiToPi(double angle);
    __host__ __device__ double  degToRad(double angle);
             __device__ double  radToDeg(double angle);
};

class                               Cartesian
{
public:
    double                          _X;
    double                          _Y;
    double                          _Z;

private:
    double                          _m;

public:
    __host__ __device__             Cartesian(double x, double y, double z) : _X(x), _Y(y), _Z(z), _m(-1) {}
};

class                       Propagator
{
public:
    double                  _iDeg;
    double                  _a;
    double                  _omega_0;
    double                  _OMEGA_0;
    double                  _omega_r;
    double                  _OMEGA_r;
    double                  _rho;
    double                  _SinI;
    double                  _CosI;
    double                  _p;
    double                  _e;
    double                  _ReKm;
    double                  _n0;
    double                  _n_bar;
    double                  _M0;
    double                  _sqrt_e;
    int                     _orbitCase = -1;
    double                  _WdeltaRad;
    double                  _precessionRateRad;
    double                  _artificialPrecessionRad = DBL_MIN;
    double                  _simulationDuration = DBL_MIN;
    double                  _incrementWdeltaRad;

    void                    propagator(double               smaKm,
                                       double               incDeg,
                                       double               e,
                                       double               raanDeg,
                                       double               aopDeg,
                                       double               trueAnomalyDeg,
                                       bool                 stationKeeping,
                                       double               WdeltaDeg,
                                       bool                 precessionMechanismSupplied,
                                       double               precessionRateDeg);
    __device__ Cartesian    evaluate(double                 timeSec,
                                     double                 simulationDuration,
                                     double                 artificialPrecessionRad,
                                     bool                   ECImode);
    __device__ double       solveKepler(double              M,
                                        double              e,
                                        double              epsilon);
    __device__ Cartesian    rotateOrbitalElements(Cartesian pq0,
                                                  double    omega,
                                                  double    OMEGA,
                                                  double    CosI,
                                                  double    SinI);
};

#endif /* !PROPAGATORSAT_CUH_ */

__host__ __device__ double  Global::myAcos(double angle)
{
    return (acos(((angle > 1) ? (1) : (angle < -1) ? (-1) : (angle))));
}

__device__ double   Global::myAsin(double angle)
{
    return (asin(((angle > 1) ? (1) : (angle < -1) ? (-1) : (angle))));
}

__host__ __device__ double  Global::degToRad(double angle)
{
    return (angle * M_PI / 180.0);
}

__device__ double   Global::radToDeg(double angle)
{
    return (angle * 180.0 / M_PI);
}

__host__ __device__ double  Global::negPiToPi(double angle)
{
    double          output;

    output = fmod(angle, TWO_PI);
    output = fmod(angle + TWO_PI, TWO_PI);
    return ((output > M_PI) ? (output - TWO_PI) : (output));
}

void        Propagator::propagator(double smaKm, double incDeg, double e, double raanDeg, double aopDeg, double trueAnomalyDeg, bool stationKeeping, double WdeltaDeg, bool precessionMechanismSupplied, double precessionRateDeg)
{
    double          iRad, trueAnomalyRad, cosV, E, mu;
    Global          global;

    _iDeg = incDeg;
    iRad = global.degToRad(_iDeg);
    _CosI = cos(iRad);
    _SinI = sin(iRad);
    _e = e;
    _a = smaKm;
    trueAnomalyRad = global.degToRad(trueAnomalyDeg);
    if (e == 0)
        _M0 = trueAnomalyRad;
    else
    {
        cosV = cos(trueAnomalyRad);
        E = global.myAcos((e + cosV) / (1 + e * cosV));
        if (global.negPiToPi(trueAnomalyRad) < 0)
            E = M_PI * 2 - E;
        _M0 = E - e * sin(E);
    }
    _OMEGA_0 = global.degToRad(raanDeg);
    _omega_0 = global.degToRad(aopDeg);
    _p = _a * (1 - e * e);
    _ReKm = global._ITURadEarth / 1000;
    mu = global._ITUGravCst;
    _n0 = sqrt(mu / pow(_a, 3));
    _n_bar = _n0 * (1.0 + 1.5 * global._ITUJ2 * pow(_ReKm, 2) / pow(_p, 2) * (1.0 - 1.5 * pow(_SinI, 2)) * pow(1.0 - pow(e, 2), 0.5));
    _OMEGA_r = -1.5 * global._ITUJ2 * pow(_ReKm, 2) / pow(_p, 2) * _n_bar * _CosI;
    _omega_r = 1.5 * global._ITUJ2 * pow(_ReKm, 2) / pow(_p, 2) * _n_bar * (2.0 - 2.5 * pow(_SinI, 2));
    _sqrt_e = sqrt((1 + e) / (1 - e));
    _WdeltaRad = global.degToRad(WdeltaDeg);
    _precessionRateRad = global.degToRad(precessionRateDeg);
    if (stationKeeping == false)
        _orbitCase = 1;
    else if (precessionMechanismSupplied == false)
        _orbitCase = 2;
    else
        _orbitCase = 3;
}

__device__ Cartesian    Propagator::rotateOrbitalElements(Cartesian pq0, double omega, double OMEGA, double CosI, double SinI)
{
    double              CosOMEGA, SinOMEGA, CosOmega, SinOmega, R11, R12, R13, R21, R22, R23, R31, R32, R33, x, y, z;

    CosOMEGA = cos(OMEGA);
    SinOMEGA = sin(OMEGA);
    CosOmega = cos(omega);
    SinOmega = sin(omega);
    R11 = CosOMEGA * CosOmega - SinOMEGA * SinOmega * CosI;
    R12 = -CosOMEGA * SinOmega - SinOMEGA * CosOmega * CosI;
    R13 = SinOMEGA * SinI;
    R21 = SinOMEGA * CosOmega + CosOMEGA * SinOmega * CosI;
    R22 = -SinOMEGA * SinOmega + CosOMEGA * CosOmega * CosI;
    R23 = -CosOMEGA * SinI;
    R31 = SinOmega * SinI;
    R32 = CosOmega * SinI;
    R33 = CosI;
    x = R11 * pq0._X + R12 * pq0._Y + R13 * pq0._Z;
    y = R21 * pq0._X + R22 * pq0._Y + R23 * pq0._Z;
    z = R31 * pq0._X + R32 * pq0._Y + R33 * pq0._Z;
    Cartesian           cart = Cartesian(x, y, z);

    return (cart);
}
__device__ Cartesian    Propagator::evaluate(double timeSec, double simulationDuration, double artificialPrecessionRad, bool ECImode = true)
{
    double              M, E, v, cosV, sinV, rotationAngleECF, omega, OMEGA;
    Global              global;

    if (_simulationDuration != simulationDuration || _artificialPrecessionRad != artificialPrecessionRad)
    {
        _simulationDuration = simulationDuration;
        _artificialPrecessionRad = artificialPrecessionRad;
        _incrementWdeltaRad = (_WdeltaRad * 2) / _simulationDuration;
    }
    M = _M0 + ((_orbitCase == 3) ? _n0 : _n_bar) * timeSec;
    E = E = (_e == 0) ? M : solveKepler(M, _e, 1e-8);
    v = 2.0 * atan(_sqrt_e * tan(E / 2));
    cosV = cos(v);
    sinV = sin(v);
    _rho = _p / (1 + _e * cosV);
    rotationAngleECF = (ECImode) ? 0 : -1 * (global._J2000AngleRad + timeSec * global._ITUAngleRateEarthRotRad);
    omega = _omega_0 + ((_orbitCase == 3) ? 0 : _omega_r * timeSec);
    OMEGA = _OMEGA_0 + rotationAngleECF + ((_orbitCase == 3) ? 0 : _OMEGA_r * timeSec);
    if (_orbitCase == 1)
        OMEGA += artificialPrecessionRad * timeSec;
    else if (_orbitCase == 2)
        OMEGA += _WdeltaRad * ((2.0 * timeSec / _simulationDuration) - 1);
    else if (_orbitCase == 3)
        OMEGA += _precessionRateRad * timeSec - _WdeltaRad + _incrementWdeltaRad * timeSec;
    Cartesian pq0 = Cartesian(1000 * _rho * cosV, 1000 * _rho * sinV, 0);

    Cartesian positionECI = Propagator::rotateOrbitalElements(pq0, omega, OMEGA, _CosI, _SinI);

    return (positionECI);
}
__device__ double   Propagator::solveKepler(double M, double e, double epsilon)
{
    double          En, Ens;

    En = M;
    Ens = En - (En - e * sin(En) - M) / (1 - e * cos(En));
    while (abs(Ens - En) > epsilon)
    {
        En = Ens;
        Ens = En - (En - e * sin(En) - M) / (1 - e * cos(En));
    }
    return (Ens);
}

__global__ void kernel(Propagator *CUDA_prop)
{
    size_t      tid;

    tid = (blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    //if (tid < NB_IT)
    Cartesian positionNGSOsatECI = CUDA_prop[0].evaluate(STEP * tid, 615359.772, 0);
}

int     main(void)
{
    cudaEvent_t     start, stop;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate(&stop));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord(start, 0));
    Propagator  prop[1], *CUDA_prop;
    dim3        block(1000, 1, 1);
    dim3        thread(1024, 1, 1);

    prop[0].propagator(7847.3, 53, 0, 18, 0, 67.5, true, 5, true, 3.4000000596279278E-05);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&CUDA_prop, sizeof(Propagator)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(CUDA_prop, prop, sizeof(Propagator), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    kernel <<< block, thread >>> (CUDA_prop);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaFree(CUDA_prop));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord(stop, 0));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));
    float           elapsedTime;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop));
    printf("time : %f ms\n", elapsedTime);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy(start));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy(stop));
    return (0);
}
```

If i launch that amount of "threads ?" it work until approximately 300k blocks. But sometime for the same amount it doesn't work. I get an error : "unknown error" from the line :

```
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

or cudaFree, or some function after the kernel call.
    enter code here

if I launch with only 1k blocks and 1k threads and use cuda-memcheck I get the same error as before but without cuda-memcheck it run great.

I don't know what cause this problem and how to solve it

NB : HANDLE_ERROR macro can be changed by gpuErrchk maccro, it's a define from a library that do exactly the same thing

And I wanted to know also how to determine the maximum amount of threads I can launch with spec' of the hardware or anything.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the [watchdog timer](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/459869/cuda-programming-and-performance/-quot-display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-quot-wddm-timeout-detection-and-recovery-/) kicking in. How long is your kernel running before it fails?

Comment: Is your GPU a dedicated compute device or do you also use it for display?

Comment: I also use my GPU for display and the kernel run for approximatelly 2100 ms for 300k blocks and 1024 threads, ~700ms for 100k Blocks and 1024 threads. For the watchdog, i looked earlyer and it's set to 6 or 7 sec. When it fail it do not run more than 3sec

Comment: Sounds even more like the watchdog timer. Are you on Windows? Are you launching multiple kernels consecutively? Windows drivers by default batch kernels to reduce launch overhead. You can force separate launches by placing a `cudaStreamQuery(0)` in between launches.

Comment: I only launch this kernel in this program. On the final i'll just launch 2 kernel, one after the other with some CPU calculation between. I'll try with cudaStreamQuery. Actually i'm working on widows 7 on VS2013. Edit : cudaStreamQuery must be check as previous function or like follo : while (cudaStreamQuery(0) != cudaSuccess); ??

Comment: A simple `cudaStreamQuery(0);`, discarding the returned value is enough to immediately launch all batched kernels awaiting execution. To ensure there are no previous kernels batched up already, it is also useful to place one call before the kernel launch.

Comment: So i decided to change the watchdog timeout, increase it to 50. And when i commented the line with : cudaDeviceSynchronize() it worked everytime for 300k blocks, but if i launch 400k blocks it seems that i got an infinite loop.. not exactly, just the GPU stop running but the program is still running. (if i do the loop with the cudaStreamQuery), If i just call the function i get an error on the cudaFree. Must i keep the cudaDeviceSynchronize too ?

Comment: Yes - `cudaStreamQuery(0)` will just asynchronously start execution, immediately moving on to the following code. `cudaDeviceSynchronize` will also wait for the kernel(s) to finish, so that results are available for further processing.

Comment: Ok i did as you said and i worked for the first launch for 400k but now I can't even launch 300k anymore... I get error on following cudaFunction as 'cudaEventSynchrnonize' "unknown error" And i increase the watchdog timer. So seems to be a dead end

Comment: Rather than increasing the timeout for longer kernels, try launching more kernels. This will allow the GUI to update in between, which is the motivation behind having a watchdog timer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows using the WDDM driver multiple kernel launches can get batched up to reduce launch overhead. As the watchdog timer applies to an entire batch, this can trigger a timeout even if each kernel by itself finishes within the chosen timeout value.

A cheap way of enforcing immediate execution of all kernels batched up so far is a call to `cudaStreamQuery(0)`. Unlike calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` this will return immediately and not wait for the kernels to complete.

Scattering `cudaStreamQuery(0)` between kernel invocations thus ensures the WDDM timeout only applies to the kernels between two `cudaStreamQuery(0)` calls.

If even a single kernel takes too long and triggers the watchdog, try splitting it up into multiple invocations with fewer blocks each, and again call `cudaStreamQuery(0)` in between. This not only makes the watchdog happy, but also keeps the GUI somewhat reactive.

Comment: I did what you said. Use cudaStreamQuery between multiple kernel calls and before and even after, i split my kernel into multiple kernel to launch less blocks. But i got the same problem. 5min ago i could launch <<< 400000, 1024 >>> Now i can't even launch <<< 200000, 1024 >>> and i tried maybe 15 sec later i can launch <<< 200000, 1024 >>> kernel...

Comment: Then reduce the block count even more. I personally would aim for something like 0.1s on a slow or 0.01s on a fast GPU, which a) keeps the GUI vaguely responsive, b) is still far from the watchdog timeout and c) still is very efficient even if you upgrade to a 10x faster GPU.

Comment: Or get a separate GPU for display and put the GPU into TCC mode (if supported, otherwise switch to Linux :) ).

Comment: I'd like to dedicate the GPU for calculation but the motherboard didn't have display/VGA/DVI or something else. So i'll try to do something stable. Thank BTW =)