# Running CUDA on GeForce for 5+ seconds? Any success stories?

Tags: cuda, timeout, driver, nvidia

The WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model) has a "watchdog" timer (called: TDR) that causes programs using the primary graphics adapter to time out if they run longer than the maximum allowed time... which is a few seconds.

[NVIDIA recommends that CUDA is run on a secondary GPU that is NOT attached to a display](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq#Programming) and does not have the Windows desktop extended onto it.

[Some guy at Puget Systems tested this](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Working-around-TDR-in-Windows-for-a-better-GPU-computing-experience-777/):

> I wondered if it might only happen if the card that was becoming
>   unresponsive was the primary one, driving the actual GUI / display. So
>   I put both GeForce cards in (980 Ti and Titan X) and ran the benchmark
>   test on just the secondary card... but it still tripped TDR.

Not very promising.

So, are there any **success stories of CUDA on a GeForce** (installed as secondary graphics adapter and not connected to any display) **running longer than 5 seconds?**

Comment: You can certainly run CUDA for more than 5 seconds - just divide the work into portions so that each [batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700645/cuda-kernel-only-launches-and-runs-at-some-grid-sizes#39703032) runs for less than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable WDDM TDR level thanks to registry to make your GPU work more than 5s

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918(v=vs.85).aspx setting TDRLevel to 0 Do the job (i've this setting on my current machine) don't forget to restart your computer for the update to work.

Comment: Thank! But i am still curious if somebody actually got CUDA running on a secondary GeForce for as long as it takes, without changing TDR settings. Just like what NVIDIA recommends: "[run CUDA on a GPU that is NOT attached to a display and does not have the Windows desktop extended onto it](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq#Programming)."

Comment: i use the integrated intel HD GPU for my screen and the NVIDIA GPU for computing, the only way to get it works was to play with WDDM settings.

Comment: Is your NVIDIA GPU disconnected from any display?

Comment: yes nothing is plugged to my NVIDIA GPU, it is only used for CUDA computing

Comment: Thanks! So, you changed WDDM settings. Does this affect the iGPU as well? In other words: is the timeout limit for the iGPU changed as well?

Comment: i'm not a Windows expert but i suppose changing these settings make changes for all graphic drivers loaded.